# Removing UIVisualEffect from AVPlayerViewController.customoverlayViewController

Tags: uikit, avplayerviewcontroller

I am implementing AVPlayerViewController.customOverlayViewController and I was wondering if there is a way to remove the UIVisualEffect and apply a clear background on the presentation. I am attaching a screenshot with the view Hirechay.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the view hierarchy, the ChannelViewController is part of the AVxCustomOverlayHostViewController, and its view of type AVxHostView includes the UIVisualEffectView. So:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    // Remove UIVisualEffectView
    if let parent = parent {
        parent.view.subviews.filter({ $0 is UIVisualEffectView }).forEach({ $0.alpha = 0 })
    }
}
```

If you want you can also remove it.

Comment: This answer is great!. How can we remove bottom margin?

Comment: Glad it helped! Regarding Bottom, I am not sure. Maybe try to debug "parent.view" (AVxHostView) frame or constraints...

Comment: Could you try on your side and share your experience? Thanks!

Comment: I found a solution! Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Reimond Hill's answer is great. Thank you for it.
You may need to remove the bottom spacing and fix height to build the exactly same overlay view that fills screen's full width and height on storyboard or xib file. In this case, we have to modify the constraints.

This is what I see at console log pannel.

```
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002dd1d10 AVxHostView:0x7fc3163678f0.height == 1140  (active)>
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d800f0 UIView:0x7fc312c8ff10.bottom == AVxHostView:0x7fc3163678f0.bottom - 60  (active)>
```

The solution to fix this:

```
if let parent = parent {
    parent.view.subviews.filter({ $0 is UIVisualEffectView }).forEach({ $0.alpha = 0 })
        
    for constraint in parent.view.constraints {
        if let second = constraint.secondItem as? UIView,
            second == parent.view,
            constraint.secondAnchor == parent.view.bottomAnchor {
            constraint.constant = 0
        }
    }
            
    for constraint in parent.view.constraints {
        if let first = constraint.firstItem as? UIView,
            first == parent.view,
            constraint.firstAttribute == .height {
            constraint.constant = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
        }
    }
}
```